# connecting to a weird SMTP server

Tags: c, sockets, email, smtp

I've written a code, which connects to basically every SMTP server available except 1. The issue is, the server sends some messages in multiple frames, for instance:

```
C: EHLO domain

S: 220 smtp.horribleserver.com welcome ESMTP  <-- 1 frame
S: 250-STARTTLS                               <-- 1 frame
   250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
   250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
   250-SIZE 120000000
   250 HELP

C: STARTTLS

S: STARTTLS ready
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN                       <-- 1 frame
S: 250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN                       <-- 1 frame
S: 250-SIZE 120000000                         <-- 1 frame
S: 250 HELP                                   <-- 1 frame
```

I tried rewriting the receive function to handle multiple frame replies:

```
int ReceiveData()
{
    int res, i = 0;
    fd_set fdread;
    timeval time;
    int s = 1;
    int iCurrentSize = 0;
    time.tv_sec = 5;
    time.tv_usec = 0;
    char cBuffer[1024] = "";
    if (RecvBuf == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    memset(RecvBuf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&fdread);
        FD_SET(hSocket, &fdread);
        if ((res = select(hSocket + 1, &fdread, NULL, NULL, &time)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            FD_CLR(hSocket, &fdread);
            return -1;
        }
        if (res == 0)
        {
            //timeout
            printf("S: %s\n", RecvBuf);
            FD_CLR(hSocket, &fdread);
            return (iCurrentSize + 1);
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(hSocket, &fdread))
        {
            s = recv(hSocket, cBuffer, sizeof(cBuffer), 0);
            if (s < 0)
            {
                FD_CLR(hSocket, &fdread);
                return -1;
            }
            if (iCurrentSize >= BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                return -2;
            }
            memcpy(&RecvBuf[iCurrentSize], cBuffer, s);
            iCurrentSize += s;
        }
    }
}
```

`RecvBuffer` points to memory on heap of size `BUFFER_SIZE`.

I've tried to timeouts of up to 30 sec, but the result is always the same:

```
S: 220 smtp.horribleserver.com welcome ESMTP  
S: 250-STARTTLS                               
   250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
   250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
   250-SIZE 120000000
   250 HELP
```

I was expecting to get the following:

```
S: 220 smtp.horribleserver.com welcome ESMTP  
   250-STARTTLS                               
   250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
   250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
   250-SIZE 120000000
   250 HELP
```

i.e. all replies stored in the same buffer once a timeout occurs.

Any idea why my code does not return the expected result?

Comment: Your `EHLO` is out of order. The server sends first, so what you're getting is consistent with expected behavior. You also should be returning not after a timeout, but when you see a line which lacks a `-` after the response code. That is what indicates when a partial response is complete.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Which `EHLO`do you mean? I actually for got to paste the `EHLO` after `STARTTLS`. But it was definitely sent.

Comment: @DarkFalcon never mind. I messed up my copying and pasting ... From what I understood by your comment, the last line the replies must always be missing the `-`. Correct?

Comment: Yes. The server sends a banner response upon connection. The `EHLO` is sent by the client after that banner. A line missing the `-` indicates the end of a server response.

Comment: What you get and what you except looks the same to me. Be aware that TCP sends a stream. The number of read calls necessary to receive all data sent it just limited by the number of characters sent by the server. Although quiet unlikely it could take 42 calls to read() to get the 42 bytes sent by the server.

Comment: [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) is the official SMTP protocol specification. [Section 4.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.2) outlines the format used for both single-line and multi-line SMTP replies: `Reply-line = *( Reply-code "-" [ textstring ] CRLF ) Reply-code [ SP textstring ] CRLF`

Comment: **TCP is a *stream*-based protocol**. There are no "frames" of TCP data. You might get 1 byte, or many k.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Problem solved by reading till timeout or a missing '-' in line. This is what I was actually missing in my code. Could someone please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Although answered already in the comments, I'm going to add an answer for completeness, but feel a bit bad for stealing the answer, so will add to it as much as I can.

For SMTP you would connect to the port then read from the socket line by line, so writing a ReadLine function returning the data as a string would be handy first step. This function would just read byte by byte until it finds the \r\n (carriage return/line feed) combination of bytes.

On initial connect, you would read each line until you get one containing "220 " meaning server ready - notice the space, as the server ready banner (and subsequent replies) can be multiline by including a hyphen after the code.
So you could have something like

```
220-xxx
220 Server Ready - this is the end of the reply
```

You now send your "EHLO" part of the handshake hoping for a 250 reply, so read line by line until the reply line starts with "250 " - again notice the space as although you will, as you noticed, typically get a "250 START" you will often receive a bunch of lines beginning with "250-", before the final line with the space after the 250

Yahoo mail server currently gives us a good example of this :

```
220 mta1262.mail.bf1.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
250-mta1262.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41943040
250-8BITMIME
250 STARTTLS
```

Where 250 STARTTLS is the end of the reply.

As pointed out above, this is all part of [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) specification.

Although the OP does not need this solution anymore, I hope it is of help to someone else.